# Unit testing angular router events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli

I have a module that shows a loading screen on navigation. How do I test that the `isLoading` variable updates on `NavigationStart`, `NavigationEnd`, etc.?

```
component.html
<app-loader *ngIf="isLoading"></app-loader>

component.ts
    this.router.events
      .subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.isLoading = true;
          // alert('NavigationStart:' + event);
        } else if (
          event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel
        ) {
          this.isLoading = false;
          // alert('NavigationEnd:' + event);
        } else if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          this.isLoading = false;
          // console.log('NavigationError: ', event);
        }
      });
```

Comment: You'll want to provide your own Router mock, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901047/angular-6-how-to-mock-router-events-url-response-in-unit-test)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - how to mock router.events url response in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901047/angular-6-how-to-mock-router-events-url-response-in-unit-test)